# Highest number of continuous zeros in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In Haskell, I have this:

```
import Numeric
import Data.Char
import Data.List

   toBin :: Integer -> Integer
   toBin n = read (showIntAtBase 2 intToDigit n "")

    -- λ> toBin 558745840
    -- 100001010011011100100011110000
    -- (0.01 secs, 117,680 bytes)

    digits :: Integer -> [[Integer]]
    digits n = group [read[d] | d <- show n]

    -- λ> digits (toBin 558745840)
    -- [[1],[0,0,0,0],[1],[0],[1],[0,0],[1,1],[0],[1,1,1],[0,0],[1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0]]
    -- (0.01 secs, 288,624 bytes)
```

And, I have to generate a function that says the highest number of zeros in a row that has the binary number, but I don't know how to do it. In other words,

```
f :: Integer -> Integer
f 558745840 = 4
f 2018 = 3
f 529 = 4
```

`f 558745840 = 4` because 1**0000**101001101110010001111**0000**, it has 4 (maximum number of) ceros in row.

Could you help me please? Maybe the title of the question could be changed, bit I don't know to summary in a question, sorry.

Comment: I would *really* recommend not to work on numbers whose decimal representation represents a binary pattern. Either work on lists of booleans (or of chars, if you must - i.e. the string that `showIntAtBase 2` returns) or just use the number directly as binary.

Comment: I don't understand what you`re sayinh

Comment: I'm saying that using the value `100₁₀` (hundred) to represent `100₂` (four) is an absolutely horrible idea. Do not use that `toBin` function you posted.